# Improper Closing

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question: [What is the Catholic Church’s position on the legalization of drugs such as marijuana or cocaine?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91523/what-is-the-catholic-church-s-position-on-the-legalization-of-drugs-such-as-mari?noredirect=1#comment257508_91523)

The question was closed due to it being a “duplicate”. But when I examined the two questions that the question was a supposed duplicate of, they didn’t answer my question. My question asked about legalization, and I specifically clarified I wasn’t talking about the morality of use. Can someone please explain what I’m missing here?

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you. Your question revolves around the **legalization** of certain drugs! It is now reopened.